# How to keep the right done tag while updating statistics?

Tags: org-mode

I have defined an [additional TODO state](http://orgmode.org/manual/Per_002dfile-keywords.html) in my org-mode file.

```
#+SEQ_TODO: TODO(t) WAIT(w) HAZY(h) | DONE(d) FINE(f)
```

`DONE` means "I am ready" and `FINE` means "It is accepted".

I use hierarchical TODOs and <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>#</kbd> to update the headlines. This is an example.

```
** DONE [#1] Headline [3/4]
   SCHEDULED: <2016-01-11 Mo>
*** Description
*** FINE First task
    CLOSED: [2016-01-15 Fr 10:57]
*** FINE Second task
    CLOSED: [2016-01-15 Fr 15:33]
*** FINE Third task
    CLOSED: [2016-01-15 Fr 16:13]
```

When I update the headline `org-update-statistics-cookies` does not mark the headline as `FINE`. Even worse: when I manually set the state of the headline to `FINE` it gets changed back to `DONE`.

My intention is to mark the headline as `DONE` as long as there is a child marked `DONE` and if all children are marked with `FINE` the parent should also marked as `FINE`. Later on I want to define an agenda view containing everything but those marked as `FINE`.

I tired to find the right position in the source, but I am a bit lost. The function `org-update-statistics-cookies` calls `org-update-parent-todo-statistics` and I think this is a good candidate to cause the error, but I am not sure, because I still did not find the exact line where the `DONE` gets written.

Can anybody help me to find it?